# Is it possible to display data in RadGrid vertically rather than horizontally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, radgrid

Is it possible to display data in the `RadGrid` vertically rather than horizonatally?

I currently have a RadGrid that displays several columns. For example:

- Product Id
- Product Name
- Price

Is there any way I change the orientation of the `RadGrid` to display the data vertically instead of horizontally?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The `RadListView` would be more appropriate for this:

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="lst" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("Col1")%></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("Col2")%></td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("Col3")%></td>
            </tr>                                 
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might help: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/transposing-rows-gt-grids-and-vice-versa.aspx